# matlab interpretation of johansen cointegration test

Tags: cointegration, matlab

I need some help understanding the results of Johansen Cointegration test run on MATLAB. I am quite new to econometrics and do not fully comprehend what MATLAB has come up with. I would be really in debt if someone could explain the following in layman terms.

The test was run on two series.

```
Data: Y
Effective sample size: 1871
Model: H1
Lags: 0
Statistic: trace
Significance level: 0.05


r  h  stat      cValue   pValue   eigVal   
========================================
0  0  11.0750   15.4948  0.2115   0.0037  
1  1  4.2114    3.8415   0.0402   0.0022
```

h =

```
      r0       r1   
t1    false    true
```

pValue =

```
      r0         r1      
t1    0.21149    0.040163
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test fails to reject the null hypothesis of no cointegration since the p-value for `r0` is greater than 0.10, and, instead, it rejects the null hypothesis of 1° rank cointegration `r1` at 5.0 % level of significance (since the p-value is 4.01 %).

So, looking at the test results, the series are not cointegrated, although I suggest to check for higher ranks and level of cointegration (`r2`, `r3`,...).

You can find more references about the test on [mathworks](http://it.mathworks.com/help/econ/identify-cointegration.html#bsxb_kf) and on the quant.stackexchange [site](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/how-to-interpret-results-of-johansen-test?rq=1) about the Johansen interpretation test in R.

Comment: Hi Quantopic, I did a little reading on Johansen's test. correct me if i am wrong, but shouldn't we compare the stat value with cvalue?

Comment: Yes you're right @cryptex. This http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/how-to-interpret-results-of-johansen-test?rq=1 question is an example of what you commented about (even if it is in R and not in MATLAB). Looking at the p-values as to the stats is the same thing anyway.

Comment: @cryptex if the answer has been helpful, please consider the possibility to check the question as answered or upvote.